# Line integral parametrization hyperbola

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is to find the area under the surface $f(x,y) = e^{x^{2}}\sin y $ along the path that is the right branch of the hyperbola $4x^2 - y^2 = 1 $ with $-1 \leq y \leq 1$, oriented so that $y$ increases.

I tried the usual substitution: $x = \dfrac{1}{2} \sec \theta$ and $y = \tan(\theta)$ and the integral got too complicated. Wondering if there's an easier parametrization?

Comment: Just checking: Are you sure the problem is correctly stated, and that you're not meant to estimate the integral numerically? (In case it's of interest, reparametrizing an integral amounts to making a substitution, so if there's no helpful substitution there's no helpful reparametrization.)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. The question explicitly says: $Evaluate \int_{C} f \cdot dr$ for the path of the right branch of that hyperbola, with those y boundaries.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for the _signed_ area. :) The function is odd in $y$ (i.e., $f(x, -y) = -f(x, y)$ for all $x$ and $y$), and the curve of integration is symmetric.